# Spring - Classcast exception as CGLIB proxy cannot be forced

Tags: java, spring, proxy, classcastexception, cglib

Here's the scenario that's driving me nuts.

1. I have a class that has a lookup method - createOther()
2. createOther should create an object of type Other. Other implements OtherInterface and in addition has a method doSomething that's marked @Async
3. Since Other implements OtherInterface, Spring gives me a JDK proxy that I cant cast as Other.
4. Spring docs suggest using `<aop:config proxy-target-class="true">` - but I'm a newbie to that and using that doesnt seem to help.

Question: how do I tell Spring that I need a CGLib proxy that targets the Other class?

Code below fails with a classcastexception.

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy4 cannot be cast to scratch.Other
at scratch.App$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$82d16307.createOther(<generated>)
at scratch.App.main(App.java:19)
```

**App.java:**

```
public class App {
public Other createOther() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

public static void main(final String[] args) {

    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("appcontext.xml");
    App app = (App) context.getBean("app");
    Other oth = app.createOther();
    oth.doSomething();
    System.out.println("Other created");
}
```

}

** Other.java **

```
public interface OtherInterface {

}

class Other implements OtherInterface {

@Async
public void doSomething() {
    System.out.println("did something");
}
}
```

** appcontext.xml **

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">
<aop:config proxy-target-class="true"></aop:config>
<bean name="app" class="scratch.App">
    <lookup-method bean="otherBean" name="createOther" />
</bean>

<bean name="otherBean" class="scratch.Other" scope="prototype">
</bean>
<task:executor id="workflowExecutorSvcPool" pool-size="5-50"
    queue-capacity="1000" keep-alive="60" />
<task:annotation-driven executor="workflowExecutorSvcPool" />

</beans>
```

Comment: what's the exact exception message. And stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

Everything seems fine - this is the proper way to tell spring to use cglib proxies. In fact, the [documentation states](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html) that it will by default make cglib proxies. The only requirement is to have cglib on your classpath. Make sure you have the cglib jar.

Comment: Yes - cglib-nodep is on the classpath. In fact, the App class is subclassed using CGLIB as shown in the stacktrace.

Comment: @Raghu - is this the exact `Other` class that you are using? If not, can you show the real class, as it is.

Comment: yes - this is the exact `Other` class. I just wrote up the App and Other classes to isolate the isuse.

Comment: doesnt change anything - spring still sees that the class implements 'OtherInterface' and gives me a JDKDynamicProxy

Answer (score 1):

The `task:annotation-driven` element should support a `proxy-target-class` attribute of its own that would need to be set to true for cglib proxies, for example

Answer (score 0):

```
Other oth = app.createOther();
```

This line is the issue. As the object returned is actually a proxy the method `createOther()` should return a `OtherInterface` which the proxy will implement.

It it trying to cast the Proxy version of the `OtherInterface` to the `Other` class and failing.